# Migrating contacts on Windows 10(thunderbird) to Ubuntu(thunderbird)

Tags: migration

I have windows 10 on my computer together with Ubuntu 1404. windows 10 has been operating Outlook as email client and also has Thunderbird installed.Ubuntu 1404 is running on the same hdd virtually with VM software and has Thunderbird installed.I want to migrate my contacts from Outlook running on windows 10 to thunderbird  on Ubuntu.Part of my contact list  is already on a .csv file which I have pulled into Thunderbird on 1404.It however doesn't display correctly.It is in the contacts folder  but in spread sheet form.The import option in Thunderbird is only partially working only  a allowing to import a csv  file.

Comment: I know this is kind of cheating, but both outlook and thunderbird can sync with google contacts.  So can iphones and android phones.  So, if you create a google account, get your outlook contacts off to the google contact list, you can then sync them between all of your platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply copy your Thunderbird profile from Windows to Ubuntu and edit `~/.thunderbird/profiles.ini` accordingly. This should not only copy your contacts but also all account settings and some more data.